# Is there a way to find the values of x for a graph in a given area?

Tags: plotting

Sorry for my wording, I'm not sure what the proper term for this is. I want to find the sections of x for which the graph of some function, f(x), is in a given area. For an example of what I'm describing, I want to know how to find the thick black bars in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Is this question about the software *Mathematica*?

Comment: It is. Again sorry for my wording. I wanted to know if there was a function or some other way to do this in Mathematica.

Comment: ...is that mac os 7?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Reduce` to get the region as inequalities:

```
f[x_] := Sin[4 x] + x;
Reduce[-1 <= f[x] <= 1, x, Reals]

(* Root[{1 + Sin[4 #1] + #1 &, -1.45320652256538767403}] <= x <= 
  Root[{1 + Sin[4 #1] + #1 &, -0.71249223361378546370}] || 
 Root[{1 + Sin[4 #1] + #1 &, -0.222621770186095002502}] <= x <= 
  Root[{-1 + Sin[4 #1] + #1 &, 0.222621770186095002502}] || 
 Root[{-1 + Sin[4 #1] + #1 &, 0.71249223361378546370}] <= x <= 
  Root[{-1 + Sin[4 #1] + #1 &, 1.45320652256538767403}] *)
```

With recently introduced `NumberLinePlot` it can also be visualized easily. Most of the code below is really styling for aesthetics...

```
Module[{f},
 f[x_] := Sin[4 x] + x;
 Show[{Plot[{f[x], -1, 1}, {x, -2, 2}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Gray, Gray}, Filling -> {2 -> {3}}],
   NumberLinePlot[Reduce[-1 <= f[x] <= 1, x, Reals], x, Spacings -> 0,
     PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.008]]}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT**: If you're looking only for the visualization, it's actually possible to skip `Reduce` entirely inside `NumberLinePlot` and pass the specification (`-1 <= f[x] <= 1`) directly to it. Extra `Reduce` doesn't hurt, though...

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.